# The kittel as tachrich

Tags: minhag, clothing, death, wedding, kittel

I recently heard and was extremely moved by the idea that the [kitlen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/burial-in-kittel) worn on Pesach, Yom Kippur, and [under the chuppah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31936/why-do-some-men-wear-the-kitul-under-their-suit-jacket-at-their-wedding) are intended to resemble [tachrichim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76970/sargenes-vs-kittel) – and are, in some cases, the [actual](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3469/1516) garments in [which](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/561,2080037/Why-is-a-kittel-worn-on-Yom-Kippur.html#footnote1) the man will be buried.

It makes some basic and deep sense to me that one wears one's soon-to-be burial garments for such shattering times as Yom Kippur and the chuppah – one's personal Yom Kippur, and the moment at which one's life doubles in meaning. Nothing, it seems, could make the call to seriousness of these occasions more real, and more desperately urgent.*

I was wondering which communities used or still use the actual contemplated burial garment as beged for the chuppah, etc.

We should live to see the days of Moshiach.

---

- 

*(As for Pesach, @SimchasTorah [pointed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6535/1516) me to [this](http://havolim.blogspot.com/2009/03/fancy-kittels-mixed-messages-and-tides.html) prepossessingly charming and nimble exploration – possibly from our own [@EliezerEisenberg](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2401/eliezer-eisenberg) – of the kitl's dual symbolism and its expression in minhag. Still, I can't say I fully see why Pesach rises to the level of the others. Any comments would be welcome.)*

Comment: See [this shiur](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/897111/rabbi-shay-schachter/basic-halachos-for-the-seder-night/) starting about 36 minutes in for a dicussion of the symbolism of the kittel on Pesach.

Comment: Most Ashkenazim (and Chassidim) still donn the *kittel* by the *chupah*.

Comment: I don't get precisely the question. If it matters at my wedding I was in _kittel_ and I wear it on Pesach and Yom Kippur since then.

Comment: I think @SAH is aking: Since burial shrouds don't have any frills, buttons, ties, etc., so the silk and ornamental kittels  used for joyous occasions can't be used for burial. As opposed to the Yekkes who wear a _Sargenes_ (sp?) on RH and YK - looks like a kittel but is put on over the head, no buttons, no frills and could potentially be used for burial. Maybe. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76987/501

Comment: @DannySchoemann Pretty close to what I was asking. I added a word to my question for clarity.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/burial-in-kittel